# Getting Dual-boot to work on (non?) UEFI system.

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub, uefi

This is the first time I'm working on a Laptop with UEFI so bear with me. I'm gonna bullet-point this to make it quick:

- HP Envy 6
- Windows 7 Preinstalled
- Default BIOS setting: Legacy Support - enabled, Secure Boot - Disabled.

I'm guessing this means Windows 7 has been installed in Legacy mode i.e. without UFI.

So dual booting should be straightforward like the old days right?

I install Freya using the following method:

- Deleted HP_TOOLS (waste partition)(Due to 4 primary partition limitation)
- Shrunk Windows partition by 50gb
- Created 10GB Swap and 40GB ext4 '/' partition for ElementaryOS

The installation finishes unsuccessfully with:

```
Cannot install grub on /dev/sda: fatal error during installation
```

Now if I boot my computer, I get a Windows screen asking for the installation CD to do startup repairs. So the end result is I have neither Windows nor ElementaryOS working.

Can someone wiser help me out here? What could be going wrong?

Comment: What media are you booting from? USB or CD?

Comment: USB. It asks to select an EFI file from the pen drive to boot. I dont remember it being this way in my older laptop though.